# Change of module title

Tags: 2sxc

A customer of ours is using 2sxc and whenever they edit an item, the moduletitle is overwritten with the title from the content they just edited.
How can I prevent this from happening. They want to use the ´static´module title.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to choose a skin container for the module that has no title.  then insert a new html module above the 2sxc content/app to create your title.  Otherwise the title is built into the template of the content in 2sxc which you should be able to easily modify to be a static string instead of a dynamic title.

Answer (score 0):

The auto-update title cannot be modified. if it's really important you could suggest it as a sponsored feature.

You could also try to give the content two titles - one to show in the module, the other for whatever you need the non-module title.